# XOR шифрование для типа double

Tags: c++, шифрование, double

Как при помощи `xor` зашифровать и расшифровать массив double однобайтным ключом? Сложность возникла в том, как правильно применить побитовый xor для типа double?

Comment: Сделать приведение типа к `long long` или `char[8]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приводим к char*, а дальше - элементарно.

```
unsigned char* xorPtr = (unsigned char*)doubleArr;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(doubleArr); i++){
    xorPtr[i] ^= 0xAA;
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но не могу понять смысл  цикла, double перевели в char*, но почему тогда количество итераций цикла равно размеру массива double, ведь, если я правильно понял, 1 double это 8 char ?

Comment: А вам сколько надо ксорить? Не весь массив что ли?

Comment: Имею ввиду, что граница будет не i < sizeof(doubleArr) * 8) ?

Comment: Нет. sizeof(entity) возвращает размер entity в байтах. Если там массив - размер массива.